# mysqli_fetch_assoc creates infinite loop

Tags: php, mysqli

I have no idea why, but `mysqli_fetch_assoc` creates an infinite loop.

Can anyone see why?

---

### Page Controller

```
class EditChargesTypePageController extends PageController {
    protected function execute () {
        parent::execute();

        // Infinite Loop
        while ($chargesType = mysqli_fetch_assoc(DataManager::sharedInstance()->chargesTypes())) {
            print_r($chargesType);
        }

        $this->_templateName = "./charges/editChargesType.html";
        $this->_viewBag['title'] = "Login";
    }
}
```

---

### Data Manager

```
class DataManager extends Singleton {
    private $db;

    function __construct () {
        $this->db = new DBManager(kDBHost, kDBUser, kDBPassword, kDBDatabase);
    }

    public function chargesTypes () {
        return mysqli_query(
            $this->db->connection(),
            "SELECT * FROM " . DBManager::kTableChargesType
        );
    }

};
```

---

### DB Manager

```
class DBManager {
    private $connection;

    // Default Database
    private static $defaultDBManager;

    public static function defaultDBManager() {
        if (self::$defaultDBManager == null) {
            self::$defaultDBManager = new ITDBManager(kDBHost, kDBUser, kDBPassword, kDBDatabase);
        }

        return self::$defaultDBManager;
    }

    function __construct ($host, $username, $password, $db) {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db);
    }

    function connection() {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is with `DataManager::sharedInstance()->chargesTypes()` keep returning new resource.

Comment: Ah maaaaan, you're right.
I think I wouldn't have seen this in a hundred years.

Thank you so much!

Comment: You can either use variable to get the resource before the loop or cache the resource in the `chargesTypes` function with static variable.

Comment: Jep, I did it with the variable ;)